# LinkMovementMethod with html in recycler view links dos't click

Tags: android, html, android-recyclerview, textview

i have a recycler view that showing some items inside every time there is a `TextView` to show the item text and the text come from html but when there is a link it show as link but it's not clickable

that's code at the recycler

```
 holder.commentContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            if (currentParentComment.getContent() != null) {
                Spanned result =CommentsUtils.getCommentTextWithLink(context,currentParentComment.getContent());
                holder.commentContent.setText(result);
            } else {
                holder.commentContent.setText("");
            }
```

the text xml

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_comment"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="14dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorLink="@color/blue_link_color"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

and this the text to display

`[ <a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/iPhoneIslam/\">رابط</a> ] .`

Answer (score 0):

Actually i find the problem at my html tag i add an extra `\` so the movement method can't open that url i remove it and every thing work fine